# Select parts of one table and count rows of another

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables: people & connections

I want to select all columns from people and also count up how many connections they have in the connections table.

```
--------------------   ----------------------
| People           |   | Connections        |
--------------------   ----------------------
| person_id | name |   | cnt_id | person_id |
--------------------   ----------------------
```

I want to select all from people and select a count of how many times the person_id for that person appears in the second table.

I have been trying to figure it out, but can't. Hopefully you all can help.

Thanks!

Comment: If there is a person with no connections, do you want a row with a count of zero, or no row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a person with no connections, this will give a row with zero count:

```
SELECT
    People.person_id,
    People.name,
    COUNT(Connections.person_id) AS number_of_connections
FROM People
LEFT JOIN Connections
ON People.person_id = Connections.person_id 
GROUP BY People.person_id
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT name,count(Connection.person_id) as cnt FROM 
      People LEFT JOIN Connection ON People.person_id = Connection.person_id 
      GROUP BY Connection.person_id
```